# "TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference" while using gotoAndplay function

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I was trying to add a gameover screen with a restart button for my game.I had placed the restart button at frame 22.When my player dies it goes to frame 22 and i'm able to restart the game on clicking the button,but this message gets looped in the output area.Please help me how i can correct this issue.

Issue is not there when i remove the line

> gotoAndPlay(22);

at Frame 17,but without that i will not get the desired functionality.

Please find my code below

**At Frame 17 - Game code**

```
stop();

import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var mouseIsDown = false; 
var speed = 0; 
var score = 0; 

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,mainLoop);

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,clicked);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,unclicked);

function clicked(m:MouseEvent)
{
    mouseIsDown = true;
}

function unclicked(m:MouseEvent)
{
    mouseIsDown = false;
}

function mainLoop(e:Event)
{
    score = score + 10;

    output.text = "Score: "+score;

    if(mouseIsDown)
    {
        speed -= 2;
    }
    else
    {
        speed+=2;
    }

    if(speed > 10) speed = 10;
    if(speed < -10) speed = -10;

    player.y += speed;

    for(var i = 0; i < numChildren; i++)
    {
        if (getChildAt(i) is Cloud || getChildAt(i) is Boundary)
            {
                var b = getChildAt(i) as MovieClip;         

                if(b.hitTestObject(player))
                {
                    for(var counter = 0; counter < 12; counter++)
                    {
                        var boom = new Boom();
                        boom.x = player.x;
                        boom.y = player.y;
                        boom.rotation = Math.random() * 360;
                        boom.scaleX = boom.scaleY = 0.5 + Math.random();
                        addChild(boom);
                    }

                    player.visible = false;

                    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,mainLoop);
                    gotoAndPlay(22);
                }
            }
    }
}
```

**At frame 22 - Restart screen**

```
stop();
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

foutput.text = "Score: "+ fscore;

btn_playagain.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playagain);

function playagain(m:MouseEvent)
{
    gotoAndPlay(17);
}

btnback3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, backMain3);

function backMain3(m:MouseEvent)
{
    gotoAndPlay(1);
}
```

**At frame 1 - Main Menu screen**

```
stop();

import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.system.fscommand;

btnnewgame.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, newGame);

function newGame(m:MouseEvent)
{
    gotoAndPlay(17);
}

btnins.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, instruct);

function instruct(m:MouseEvent)
{
    gotoAndPlay(6);
}

btncredits.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, credits);

function credits(m:MouseEvent)
{
    gotoAndPlay(11);
}

btnexit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, exitfunc);

function exitfunc(m:MouseEvent)
{
    fscommand("quit");
}
```

**At Frame 6 - Instructions Screen**

```
stop();

btnback1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, backMain1);

function backMain1(m:MouseEvent)
{
    gotoAndPlay(1);
}
```

**At Frame 11 - Credits Screen**

```
stop();

btnback2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, backMain2);

function backMain2(m:MouseEvent)
{
    gotoAndPlay(1);
}
```

Comment: Show me the code from frame 22.

Comment: @tziuka sorry.i had updated my query

Answer (score 1):

That error means that you are trying to call a method on a null object, meaning one of the objects you are using on frame 22 doesn't actually exist at that moment.

The likely candidates for the offending variable are `foutput`, `btn_playagain`, and `btnback3`. Check to make sure that they are on the stage at frame 22, and are spelt correctly.

You use `output.text` on frame 17, are you sure that it should be `foutput.text` on frame 22?

Comment: Well spotted.

Error #1009 would be consistent with trying to access a a method of a misspelled object name.